What does trailing slash on void elements has no effect and interacts badly with unquoted attribute values mean?
For reference here is the head tag of one of my websites.

<!-- Basic-->
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <!-- Mobile Metas-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
  <!-- Site Metas-->
  <meta name="keywords" content="Web Development"/>
  <meta name="description" content="Neil Meyer Web Design Website"/>
  <meta name="author" content="Neil Meyer"/>
  <title>Neil Meyer</title>
  <!-- bootstrap core css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <!-- Google Font-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Madimi+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- responsive style-->
  <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- Favicon-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="./images/favicon.png">


The HTML validator on W3schools says the following...

> Info: Trailing slash on void elements has no effect and interacts 
> badly with unquoted attribute values.

I cannot understand what it means because that markup looks correct to me.


No HTML standard has ever required a closing slash on void elements. That is why it will have no effect. The standard even says it has no meaning and does nothing. It's only allowed because, at one time, it was thought we would all be using XHTML by now so it's allowed for backwards compatibility. Otherwise, many sites would break.
So follow the HTML standard and just don't put the useless slash in there. Browsers just ignore it anyway.

Thank You, for some reason I just couldn't grasp what the explanation meant just remove the slash. Void element was also a term I was unfamiliar with.
